# Finding the datasheet of an IC

Tags: identification

I'm trying to find the datasheet of an 8-pin DIP IC:[image]

I tried to search each line separately and both of them together but to no avail.

Comment: Do you have any idea what it might be? If its some micro or eeprom, then this may as well be just some custom number that says nothing at all.

Comment: A Ukrainian website states that it's 24C02 EEPROM.

Comment: If you need to replace it, you might have a problem.  It might need to be initialized with data for the device (firmware, configuration, etc.) so just putting a new chip in wouldn't help.

Comment: I just bought it, I wanted 24C02 EEPROM and that's what I got. Should have stated that in the question. Sorry, but its my first question. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be an east european clone of the well-known EEPROM 24C02. 
And saying "East European clone" I mean [that](http://spidometrs.ru/content/view/106/25/). :-)

P.S. [Some](http://pl-1.org/public/productdetail.aspx?id=12) russian [store](http://radiokomponent.com.ua/product/24c02-pc-6-c21dc/)  are selling this, but if it is equivalent to 24C02 you could buy the latter.